# RSpec expectation for Selenium/WebDriver actions

Tags: ruby, rspec, webdriver

Having defined Selenium actions (click a button, check a checkbox, type in text into input field) what would be the RSpec expectations for these actions in RSpec tests? What I mean is the following. I have a test

```
it 'Test button' do
  selenium.click(button_locator)
end
```

What rspec expectation would one normally use for this? So far I've decided to use the `raise_error` matcher and write it like this: `lambda {selenium.click(button_locator)}.should_not raise_error` It would fail if Selenium fails to find the locator.
Maybe there is another more friendly method for this?

Comment: What is it that you need to test?

Comment: If it's a button, I need to make sure it's clicked.

Comment: Are you testing for the presence of the button? Or whether Selenium is able to click it? Or would you rather confirm that a user can perform the action the button is supposed to trigger? These are different things.

Comment: @Mark Thomas I am testing if Selenium is able to click the button prior to clicking it (actually I check if the button is present and perhaps also if its clickable). Do you mean that checking that I do not need to expect (in terms of RSpec) anything from the button click action?